# Designerbehavior of custom control with DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I find a strange behavior of xaml designer with a DataGrid-CustomControl. There I have a DependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomizableColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CustomizableColumns",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
        typeof(DataGridCustomizable),
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>()));
```

In the XAML-Designer I have the following code:

```
<ctrl:DataGridCustomizable
    <ctrl:DataGridCustomizable.CustomizableColumns>
         ... the columns
```

In a overridden method

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
```

I put the CustomizableColumns to the DataGrid Columns (only in DesignMode)

Now here is my notice. The first opening of the XAML designer, after a new build, perceives nothing from the CustomizableColumns. So in OnInitialized method, no any columns are added!

Then I close and reopen the XAML designer, and only just now the CustomizableColumns are known, and the OnInitialized method puts the CustomizableColumns to the DataGrid Columns.

Do you know the reason for it? Thanks for your input!

Comment: As a note, you must not set a default value of a mutable reference type dependency property by property metadata. All instances of your control would use the same `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` object unless you explictly assign a property value. Besides that, do you really need the collection to be observable? Are collection members ever added or removed at runtime?

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely right! I still have to try it, but that's probably the problem. Thank you for your comment. If I confirm it, could you write it again as an answer so that I can mark it as "correct" for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not set a default value of a mutable reference type dependency property by property metadata. All instances of your control would use the same `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` object unless you explictly assign a property value.

You should instead set the default value by a `SetCurrentValue` call in the control's constructor.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomizableColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(CustomizableColumns),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
        typeof(DataGridCustomizable));

...

public DataGridCustomizable()
{
    SetCurrentValue(CustomizableColumnsProperty,
        new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>());
}
```

Using `SetCurrentValue` instead of just `SetValue` ensures that any Binding, Style Setter or other dependency property value source still works correctly.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks alot :-)